# Delete first two characters of elements in a list of lists

Tags: python

Let's say I have the following list of lists:

```
final_list = [[1,'pppizza',3,4],[1,'mmmonkey',9,10],[1,'dddoublerainbow',8,2]]
```

Now I need to remove the first 2 characters of the second element of every list, so the result will be:

```
final_list = [[1,'pizza',3,4],[1,'monkey',9,10],[1,'doublerainbow',8,2]]
```

Comment: @PM2Ring they are strings, I'm sorry, I should have put them in between ' '.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to rebuild the entire list from scratch just to do it in a one-line comprehension while unnecessarily iterating the inner lists. Just modify the elements that need modifying:

```
for lst in final_list:
    lst[1] = lst[1][2:]
```

Comment: Dammit! I was so close, it works, thank you very much. I tried: lst[1] = lst [1[2:]]...

Answer (score 1):

use double list comprehensions:

```
final_list = [[x if hasattr(x, '__len__') and i == 1 else x[2:] for i, x in enumerate(y)] for y in my_list]
```

this will trim the first 2 elements of the second element, even if the element is not a string

If you want it for strings only then the statement becomes:

```
final_list = [[x if type(x) == str and i == 1 else x[2:] for i, x in enumerate(y)] for y in my_list]
```

Comment: The OP only wants to modify the 2nd item in each sublist, there's no need to check each item. And if any sublists contains more than 1 string then your code would modify them all, contrary to the specification.

Answer (score 1):

```
final_list = [[x[2:] if i==1 else x for i, x in enumerate(y)] for y in my_list]
```

Full answer:

```
final_list = []
for y in my_list:
    l = []
    for i, x in enumerate(my_list):
    if i==1:  #2nd element in the list
        l.append(x[2:])  # Append a string starting from the 3rd letter to the end
    else:
        l.append(x) . # Just append the element at x
    my_list.append(l)  # Append the list l to my_list
print(my_list)
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation text to this answer.

Comment: The problem is solved (by schwobaseggl), but I am interested to know how this works, what does the enumerate(y) do?

Comment: enumerate runs through indexes and the elements of the list.
For example: for i, x in enumerate([2,3,4]):
i=0, x=2 -> i=1, x=3 -> i=2, x=4